# Magento 2 new home page template not working

Tags: magento2.2, page, custom-template

I can't get a custom page template to work in my custom theme. All I'm getting is a blank page. No header, footer, page content, nothing. I have created the following files in my custom theme:

> /Magento_Theme/layouts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">

    <layout id="custom_home">
        <label translate="true">Custom Home</label>
    </layout>

</page_layouts>
```

> /Magento_Theme/page_layouts/custom_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

I can see the new page template in the admin area and have assigned it to my page. I can also see the template name added as a class in the body, but other than that it's just a blank white page.

I'm using Magento 2.2.5. Parent theme is Blank.

Comment: `<update handle="empty"/>` should be "1column"

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal I have also tried it with that and had no success. I still get a blank page.

Answer (score -1):

I realized that the `page_layouts` folder in my theme should have been `page_layout` once I changed that everything worked as it should.